# Livereload for node.js. Is there possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, livereload

Every time i modify my node.js files from server i need to stop the server and run again node app.js to see the changes.

Is there a way to see changes without stop/start server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, **nodemon** is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server.

1. Install nodemon globally `npm install nodemon -g`
2. Run the server `nodemon app.js`